# Django filter, many queries in array

Tags: python, django, django-views

need an array where Q() object are added
filter with many value

```
Anime.objects.filter(Q(question__startswith='Who') & Q(question__startswith='What'))
```

but need something like this

```
val_arr = []
val_arr.append(Q(question__startswith='Who'))
val_arr.append(Q(question__startswith='What'))
Anime.objects.filter(val_arr)
```

Comment: can you elaborate more. your question is unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with dictionary like this:

```
filters = Q()

val_arr = dict()
val_arr.update({"question__startswith": 'Who'))
val_arr.update({"question__startswith": 'What'))

for item in val_arr:
   filters |= Q(**{item:val_arr[item]})

Anime.objects.filter(filters)
```

Comment: how did you declare the filters variable. local variable 'filters' referenced before assignment

Comment: Updated the answer check

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `&` *(AND)* operation, using `|` *(OR)* will solve your issue

So change

```
Anime.objects.filter(
    Q(question__startswith='Who') & Q(question__startswith='What')
)
```

to

```
Anime.objects.filter(
    Q(question__startswith='Who') | Q(question__startswith='What')
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Investigate the well-known [django-filters](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/usage.html) package. It may already do everything you want, allowing a user to construct his own complex queries in a view.

What you ask can be coded using the `|` or operator

```
q = val_arr[0]
for val in val_arr[1:] :
    q = q | val

Anime.objects.filter( q)
```

You need to `|` your Q objects together. The same  question cannot start both with 'Who' and with 'What'. `qs.filter(field1=val1, field2=val2)` is and-logic and you can also this by `Q(field1=val1)&Q(field2=val2)`

Comment: that's a good solution!